# Retrieve Documents from Multiple Collection

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I stored documents in Marklogic like below,

```
Collection : system, user
Documents Stored
 1. /system/user/1
 2. /system/user/2

Collection : system, role
Documents Stored
 1. /system/role/1
 2. /system/role/2

Collection : system, access
Documents Stored
 1. /system/access/1
 2. /system/access/2
```

Now my requirement is i want all the documents which are only the part of **system, access** collection so i tried,

```
for $doc in cts:search(collection(("system", "access")), ())
return 
      (  
        document-uri($doc)
      )
```

after executing above code here i am expecting **/system/access/1**, **/system/access/2** because these two documents are only part of **"system", "access"** collection but here i am getting all the documents from **Collection : system, user**, **Collection : system, role**.
I am not able to understand wrong with about Code or i am missing something.

Please help me to Fix this Issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Problem with your code is as below-

All the 6 documents which you have stored are part of "**System**" collection.

So obviously whenever you will try to give **collection("system")**, it will fetch all documents.

The other scenario can be- Suppose you want to retrieve the document which are part of "**user" and "access**" collection. In that case you can use **cts:and-query** inside **cts:search** query.

Hope that Helps !

Comment: Thx @Shalini.. after using cts:and-query it works fine.

Comment: Glad it helped :)